# Set up a reverse proxy for local domains

Tags: reverse-proxy, apache2, local-area-network

My web server (apache2) is accessible on my LAN with its host name, let's say, `jarvis` (url: `http://jarvis/`).

I have a Gitea instance running in my local network which is accessible via `http://jarvis:3000`. It obviously runs on the same machine as the webserver does and runs inside a Docker container (just as the webserver does) with container name, let's say, `gitea`. They share the same docker network so the web server can access the gitea instance through `http://gitea:3000`.

In my Pi-hole, I've set up a local DNS entry `http://git.home/` which routes to the IP address of my web server `jarvis` on `192.168.154.x`. **Now, what I want is to configure apache2 to route access via this domain to `http://gitea:3000`**.

So, I decided to alter my `000-default.conf` as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  #...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost git.home:80>
  ServerName git.home

  ProxyPass / http://gitea:3000/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://gitea:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

Now, when browsing to `http://git.home/` I keep getting to the web server root page instead of the Gitea instance.

What did I do wrong with the reverse proxy configuration? Is there anything I should keep in mind when creating reverse proxies for local domains?